# Is teleportation possible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-teleportation

When I just learned about quantum entanglement, I read that if two electrons are in quantum entanglement and placed in two different places, the photon which interacted with one electron is teleported to the other place. My question is if the teleportation of photon is possible! Is there any possibility of teleportation of large bodies?

Comment: I dont think it is correct. *photon which interacted with one electron is teleported* ... I have an impression, that the other electron is in defined state, the other photon that interacts on the other side has the same result of the interaction, but it is not really transport of matter, neither transport of information.

Comment: Did you read the article on [quantum teleportation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation) before asking this question? If yes, what about it did not satisfy you?

Comment: Excuse me,I got the information from  the famous cosmologist Dr.Brain Greene's best seller "fabric of the cosmos" chapter "quantum loop". He clearly mention in that the teleportation of photon has happened already in an experiment and it may leads to the teleportation of humans are also possible.I want clarification about that. That is why I asked here!!!

Comment: You should trust wikipedia on this. That what is teleportated is a state of a system, not system itself. No matter can be teleportated.

Comment: entanglement is not about teleportion/interaction/information-transfer, it's just statistical correlation in the usuall sense. Anyone who is talking about the above terms without mentioning the **ever present classical communication/interaction** is not telling you the truth about what entanglement really means.

Comment: @Rena - I don't think the distinction between teleporting the "state of a system" and the "system itself" has any meaning in quantum physics. For example, if you find two indistinguishable particles or systems at positions A and B at an earlier time, and at C and D at a later time, in QM there *is* no fact of the matter about whether the one at A went to C and the one at B went to D, or whether the one at A went to D and the one at B went to C.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I haven't thought of it that way. You have a terribly creepy point of view.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Star-Trek style teleportation, not *with our current knowledge*.

In various articles about the physics of Star Trek, the one thing most physicists genuinely have a problem with is the transporter. Turning 100kg of human into energy and reassembling them thousands of kilometers away with subatomic precision involves handling an awful lot of energy (the precise number of gigatons-equivalent is left as an exercise for the reader). Antimatter reactors, energy weapons, the holodeck, sentient AI, even warp drive are believed to be possible and easier than the transporter / replicator.

Now, if some bright spark has a moment of clarity and reinvents physics tomorrow, we may find that it's actually easy. And before anyone says "but law X says..." I refer you to the works of Aristotle, Archimedes, Kepler, Newton, Einstein etc. Cold, hard "facts" have been found to be completely wrong (or a special case, like newtonian mechanics) on more than one occasion.

Comment: but law X says, that it isn't possible!